# Entity Framework, mapping Views to Tables

Tags: linq, entity-framework, mapping

I have a basic view that returns the same columns as a table (give or take 1 field)

in my DAL code, i am returning a list of MyTableObject, however in some cases, i will call the view to return the same data, but from different sources.

```
List<MyTableObject> tableObjects = new List<MyTableObject>();
if (case1)
  tableObjects = entities.MyTableObjects.Where(criteria).ToList();
else
  tableObjects = entities.MyViewObjects.Where(criteria).ToList(); // <-- This will obviously break
return tableObjects;
```

is there a way to Map view entities to be returned as table entities? (other than having table and view implement the same interface and return that interface) i would like to keep the return type as MyTableObject.

I came across [Auto Mapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/), but not sure if it would be suitable for this scenario..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like i found a cool solution to this..

Initially I tried to implement interface approach and run into some [casting issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997055/entityframework-casting-issues) (using interfaces alongside my predicate builder), and also with interfaces having to create partial classes for each entity that implement the interface..

the answer.. **POCOs**.

Iused [Poco Template for EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework), and than simply edited xxxPocoGenerator.Context.tt to return MyTable object from MyViews collection (one line).

```
public ObjectSet<Trade> v_Trade {
        get { return _v_Trade  ?? (_v_Trade = CreateObjectSet<Trade>("Trades")); }
}
```

nice and easy..

Comment: I guess you would call this duck typing.  I like it.  I'm with you in that my initial thought is to kill myself with interfaces.  I like your approach better.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a stored procedure (or [CommandText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283136.aspx) in the model, without creating DB Object) that will simply call "Select * from View". Then [create Function Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx) for this procedure and set the return type to MyTableObject.