# EntityFramework Casting issues

Tags: linq, entity-framework, casting, predicate

I am building my query using PredicateBuilder from LinqKit.
it is great and does exactly what i am looking for.

To make my code more reusable (tables and views) i created a generic predicate builder class:

```
public class LocalPredicateBuilder<T> where T : IResort
...
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<T>(
```

which exposes BuildPredicate method. I can use it like this:

```
var predicate = new LocalPredicateBuilder<Resort>().BuildPredicate();
var resorts = _entities.Resorts.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

however when i try to do this, i get this runtime error (btw entity objects implement IResort): 
**Unable to cast the type 'ConsoleApplication1.Entities.Resort' to type 'ConsoleApplication1.Entities.IResort'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types**

i tried casting (didn't work):

```
var rlist = eq.Cast<Resort>().ToList();
```

Any other way i can get around this casting issue?

**UPDATE**

not having much luck getting predicates to work using interfaces.. so i [solved my problem by going with POCOs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992630/entity-framework-mapping-views-to-tables/3997782#3997782)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the error is accurate. You can't do that in an L2E query, because your interface (`IReport`) is not part of your entity model and hence can't be converted to SQL. You have to use an entity type, not an interface for that.

Answer (score 0):

just create a partial class for the entity frameowrk object and make that implement the interface.

the other way would be to create a list of the type you want

then do a for each on the linq dataset and add the items to the collection.

the problem is caused because .net doesnt know how to cast 
`List<ISomething>` into a `List<Something>`

Comment: i have. wouldn't be able to compile otherwise

Comment: the query actually returns List<Something> so it should be possible to make that cast. the ISomething is only used to create predicates used in where query.